# spring @Async : only marks candidate for Asynchronous Execution, not guaranteed?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

[@Async javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.java#L26) states that it only marks candidate for `asynchronous execution`,

1. Does this mean asynchronous execution is not guaranteed?
2. In particular, what happens to a hibernate transaction if the candidate(`postProcessor#process`) that was marked for async execution but did not run asynchronously and threw exception

```
Service{
 @Transactional
 public void save(Entity entity){
  repository.save(entity);
  asyncPostProcessor.process(entity); //threw Exception
 }
}

AsyncPostProcessor{
  @Async
  void process(Entity entity){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

A

Comment: *Does this mean asynchronous execution is not guaranteed?*  If you run out of the ability to create any more threads, then I guess it would not truly be async?